# Ternary Operator in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a LINQ query that I need to use a ternary operator on so certain joins are used based on certain criteria. So this is my query.

```
var lData = (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("campaignresponse")
             join a in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("activityparty") on ((EntityReference)r["activityid"]).Id equals ((EntityReference)a["activityid"]).Id

             //tenary statement here 
             join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)a["partyid"]).Id equals c["contactid"]

              where ((EntityReference)r["new_distributorid"]).Id.Equals(lProfileProperty.PropertyValue)
              select new
          {
              });
```

This is what I want to do.

**If r["new_distributorid"] == 1 I need to use:**

```
join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)a["partyid"]).Id equals c["contactid"]
```

**if r["new_distributorid"] == 2 then I need to use:**

```
join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account") on ((EntityReference)a["partyid"]).Id equals c["accountid"]
```

**and if r["new_distributorid"] == 3 then I need to use:**

```
join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("lead") on ((EntityReference)a["partyid"]).Id equals c["leadid"]
```

So basically is new_distributor == 1 I need to use a certain join if its a 2 I need another join and if its a 3 I need another join.

Is this possible? If it is, how would I go about setting that up?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for CRM?  If so it may help to add that as a tag as well.

Comment: Just Linq? Linq-to-EF? Linq-to-SQL? Big difference

Comment: what about creating three separate linq statements and unioning them?

Comment: Your datamodel looks really broken. Conditional joins is a real smell and should be avoided.

Comment: What results are you going to pull from the contact, account, or lead?  I'm with @JoshC., just create three queries and union them.

Comment: Since LINQ uses deferred execution you can just concatenate expression in if-else statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that's changing is a single string value, so just determine that string value before you start defining the query:

```
string tableName = "";

switch(r["new_distributorid"])
{
  case(1): 
    tableName = "contact";
  case(2): 
    tableName = "account";
  case(3): 
    tableName = "lead";
}

string tableID = tableName + "id";

//...
join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery(tableName) 
on ((EntityReference)a["partyid"]).Id equals c[tableID]
```